# how to make URL in MVC 5 SEO Friendly and Consistent?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to make my websites urls more SEO friendly, so I Used This approach to change routing.(although I don't know is this approach is Best Way or not - but this is not my Question!)

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "interface",
                url: "soal/{id}/{slug}",    /* "soal" is only decor */
                defaults:new { controller = "ui", action = "singleQuestion",
                    slug = UrlParameter.Optional}    /*I made "slug" optional because I don't need this part to retrieve conternt from database */
                                      /* slug only explains content of the webpage*/

                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

This Is The "SingleQuestion" Action that Processes pages:

```
        public ActionResult singleQuestion(int id, string slug) 
                                                   /* "slug" parameter here does nothing. Action Does not use this.*/
    {
        var questions = BQcnt.Questions;
        var showQuestion = questions.Find(id);
        if (showQuestion != null)
        {
            var AnswerOfShowQuestion = BQcnt.Answers.Where(
                i => i.QuestionID == showQuestion.QuestionID);

            ViewBag.lastQuestion = showQuestion;
            ViewBag.answer_of_show_question = AnswerOfShowQuestion;
        }
        return View(questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.QuestionID));
    }
```

well this works fine when i use these Urls:

```
http://localhost:9408/soal/13/bla-bla-bla
```

and

```
http://localhost:9408/soal/13
```

these urls direct to same pages But My only problem is this:
**when I use second url, I want when page loads automatically URL changes to Complete One and the slug append to the url, Like first One.**

edit: I want some thing exactly  Like stackoverflow.com urls.
these two urls:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615538/how-to-make-url-in-mvc-5-seo-friendly-and-consistent

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615538
```

opens same page, But when we use second one(as you can examine ) url translates to first one automatically. but my urls does not translate like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, the problem solved by myself.

```
public ActionResult singleQuestion(int id, string slug)
{
    var questions = BQcnt.Questions;
    var showQuestion = questions.Find(id);
    if (showQuestion != null)
    {
        var AnswerOfShowQuestion = BQcnt.Answers.Where(
            i => i.QuestionID == showQuestion.QuestionID);

        ViewBag.lastQuestion = showQuestion;
        ViewBag.answer_of_show_question = AnswerOfShowQuestion;
        if (slug != showQuestion.slug)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("singleQuestion", new { id = id, slug = showQuestion.slug });
        }
        else
        {
            return View(questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.QuestionID));
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

maybe it,s dirty... but perfectly works...

Comment: If you put this in an ActionFilter, you can make your controller significantly tidier :) and avoid having duplicate code in every controller you do this for